# Django RSS Feed has domain set to example.com

Tags: django, rss

I am able to get an output for the rss feed but the domain in the item link is http://example.com instead of the domain that I used in Feed.link (http://www.mydomain.com/blog). What do I need to do to get "mydomain.com" instead of "example.com"?

Below is the generated rss feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>MyDomain Blog</title>
<link>http://www.mydomain.com/blog</link>
<description>insights and new developments in creating Pushstack</description>
<atom:link href="http://example.com/blog/rss/" rel="self"></atom:link>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 31 Jan 2011 19:41:42 -0000</lastBuildDate>
<item>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link>http://example.com/blog/example</link>
    <description></description>
    <guid>http://example.com/blog/example</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Also, in the title of the browser (OS X Chrome) it says, "NameError at /blog/rss/".  Not sure if that is something that always shows up or if something else is wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`example.com` is the domain that is automatically inserted into the database via the [Sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/).

You can edit the site in the admin: http://yourserver.com/admin/sites/site/

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You can also update it directly from the DDBB from "django_site" table, in case you are not using the admin.

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The atom:link value defaults to the information in the Sites framework, but you can override it by setting a feed_link property in your feed class, eg:

```
feed_link = "http://www.mydomain.com/blog/rss"
```